# Change text color based on its background

Tags: html, css

So, I was practicing in HTML and CSS as usual and yesterday I started working on a PSD template. It seemed easy for me, but in a few seconds, I bunched in the issue that I am talking about right now.

In general, I want to change the exact part of a text based on its background. I've already tried "mix-blend-mode", but unfortunately, the result wasn't satisfying for me.

Here is what I want.
[image]

So, as you can see the text before the center is white-colored, but the text after the center has the same color as the background before the center.
Is there any way to do that using CSS or maybe even Javascript.

Comment: This also uses `mix-blend-mode` but it adapts to the background which is moving in this post. it also uses sass which is a css extension
https://css-tricks.com/reverse-text-color-mix-blend-mode/
Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<style>
.container {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.black-half div {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.white-half div {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    width:150px;
}
.white-half {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.black-half {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="black-half">
      <div>Split background and text color</div>
  </div>
  <div class="white-half">
      <div>Split background and text color</div>
  </div>
</div>
```